# Finding Duplicate Values in Multi-dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Model2345
            [1] => John Doe
            [2] => SN1234
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Model2345
            [1] => John Doe
            [2] => SN3456
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Model1234
            [1] => Jane Doe
            [2] => SN3456
        )
)
```

I want to have a way to check for duplicate values for keys [1] (the  John Doe/Jane Doe key) and [2] (the SNxxxx key) in php, but ignore duplicates for key [0].  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: you can iterate the array and check for that specific index if it has duplicate

Comment: Use `array_intersect()`.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438140/find-duplicate-value-in-multi-dimensional-array). The following is the code from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18438311/4431820) of that question.

It utilizes the `array_intersect()` function.

```
<?php
$array = array(array("test data","testing data"), array("new data","test data"), array("another data", "test data", "unique data"));
$result = array();

$first = $array[0];
for($i=1; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
    $result = array_intersect ($first, $array[$i]);
    $first = $result;
}
print_r($result);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Array ( [0] => test data )

Comment: I tried this with my array but get an empty result even when there are clearly duplicates.  Is that because your example is with integers and not strings?

Comment: I tested the code and it works just fine for strings as well. I have updated the code with the **exact** code that worked for me. Of course, this only works if there is a common value in **all three** sub-arrays, meaning it would show empty result for your example array. Are you looking for a to catch even a single repetition or just across all arrays?

Comment: Ah I see - so this wouldn't work for me.  I need to catch even a single repetition.

Comment: It seems to be fine, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = your_array();

$current = current($array);
foreach($array as $key => $val){
 $duplicate[$key] = array_intersect($current, $val);
}

echo($duplicate);
```

Comment: This almost works, but it always prints the first array regardless if there are duplicates or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$Contacts = [
  [
    'name' => 'name 1',
    'phone' => '12341234',
    'email' => 'test@web.com'
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'name 1',
    'phone' => '12341234',
    'email' => 'test@web.com'
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'name 3',
    'phone' => '4322342',
    'email' => 'test@web1.com'
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'name 4',
    'phone' => '1234123423',
    'email' => 'test@web1.com'
  ],
  [
    'name' => 'name 5',
    'phone' => '12341266634',
    'email' => 'test@eqweqwweb.com'
  ],
];

$start = microtime(true);   

    // function CheckDuplicteContacts($Contacts)
    // {
        if(count($Contacts) == 1){
            return $validator = true;
        } else {
            $DuplicateLines = [];
            foreach($Contacts as $CurrentKey => $Contact)
            {
                foreach($Contacts as $SearchKey => $SearchContact)
                {
                    
                    if(
                        (
                            ($SearchContact["name"] == $Contact["name"]) &&
                            ($SearchContact["email"] == $Contact["email"]) &&
                            ($SearchContact["phone"] == $Contact["phone"])
                        )
                        && 
                        ($SearchKey != $CurrentKey))
                    {
                        array_push($DuplicateLines,$CurrentKey + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            $validator = empty($DuplicateLines) ? true : $DuplicateLines;

        }
  //  }
    
 
var_dump($validator);

echo (microtime(true) -$start)*100;
```

This gives you the duplicates on keys. You can try something similar

You can check here - https://3v4l.org/hBtQt