# Check rows for duplicate and print those rows PHP

Tags: php

Data in DB is arranged as following:
Id - Name - RAM - Processor - storage - url

After a query where I'm filtering on the specs I've get the following arrays:

```
Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => HP [ram] => 8GB [graphcard] => 2GB [processor] => i5 [url] => store1)
Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => HP [ram] => 8GB [graphcard] => 2GB [processor] => i5 [url] => store2)
Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => HP [ram] => 8GB [graphcard] => 2GB [processor] => i5 [url] => store3)
Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Lenovo [ram] => 8GB [graphcard] => 2GB [processor] => i5 [url] => store2)
Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => Apple [ram] => 8GB [graphcard] => 2GB [processor] => i5 [url] => store1)
```

I want to get the rows where [name] is duplicate with other arrays 
In this example I would get the first three arrays.

So far I've being trying with `array_intersect_assoc` and `array_diff_assoc`
But this only returns the first difference that occurs.

Anyone familiar with a way to get the duplicates?

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438140/find-duplicate-value-in-multi-dimensional-array

Comment: where did you get that information ? are you queering a database, reading a file ?

Comment: And why did you remove the question you asked about this already? (Read it just a couple of hours ago; can’t find it any more, guess you asked it under a different account.) You already got feedback and suggestions there, so why do we have to start over now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find duplicate value in multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438140/find-duplicate-value-in-multi-dimensional-array)